# How can I display provided search parameters on an SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

How can I ensure that parameter values that I used to search for records display on a report. For example if I search for a country called Canada and after displaying records (or not) it shows on the report that I used a parameter value Canada.

I am using Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 to develop reports on SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Add a text box, with en expression that refers to the [Parameters collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337293%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

```
="Countries shown: " & IIF(Parameters!Country = "", "All", Parameters!Country)
```